# 404 when do logout in Spring Security Rest Plugin for Grails

Tags: spring, rest, grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I'm setting the security system on my project (**Grails - Angularjs**) with [Spring Security Rest Plugin](https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/) v1.5.4 (using spring security core 2.0.0) for Grails 2.4.4. Doc about this plugin can be found [here](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/1.5.4/docs/guide/index.html).

I'm testing the login and logout with postman chrome rest client and I'm able to do a login OK, but I'm getting a 404 when I do logout.

In the documentation clearly says:

> The logout filter exposes an endpoint for deleting tokens. It will
>   read the token from an HTTP header. If found, will delete it from the
>   storage, sending a 200 response. Otherwise, it will send a 404
>   response
>
> You can configure it in Config.groovy using this properties:
>
> **Config key**...................................................................................**Default
>   value**
>
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.logout.endpointUrl....................../api/logout
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName....X-Auth-Token

So, after doing a login successfully, I tried to do a logout to that url (**my_host_url/api/logout**) with a GET method and sending a header **X-Auth-Token** with the token I got previously from login.

But I keep getting a 404. See image below

[image]

***Edit***: I'm setting the chain map like this (in order to get a stateless behavior):

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                                                          // Traditional chain
]
```

So. What am I doing wrong here, or what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide your code for "logout" method, i think, resource mapping is missing either "get" method or proper "path"

Comment: @devbd, thanks for your reply! Actually I didn't implement a `logout` method. I thought the plugin added this implicitly as the `login` method. Is that correct?

Comment: please check plugin default login url. i think, the url should be only "/logout" ..

Comment: my mistake.., 
please check if grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap is set with "stateless"

Comment: 5.2. Plugin configuration
http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/

Comment: @devbd, yes, the chainMap is set with stateless. Please, See ***Edit*** in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed another excerpt from the docs. It's a warning message literally before the chunk you quoted, and says:

> Logout is not possible when using JWT tokens (the default strategy), as no state is kept in the server.
>
> If you still want to have logout, you can provide your own implementation by creating a subclass of `JwtTokenStorageService` and overriding the methods `storeToken` and `removeToken`. Then, register your implementation in `resources.groovy` as `tokenStorageService`.

Comment: Hi, @Álvaro Sánchez-Mariscal, is there a recommended tutorial that teaches how to implement the logout feature using a subclass of `JwtTokenStorageService`? I know the logout function works flawlessly when I use Spring Security Rest with GORM. Also, thanks for the great plugin :)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of